# When to use functional interface? (Java 8)

Tags: performance, java-8, functional-interface

I recently switched over to developing my software for Java 8, and I've been slowly improving my use of Java 8 and becoming comfortable with Java 8, and in doing so I've started implementing more and more functional interfaces, and recently NetBeans has started to suggest that I swap some of my for loops over to functional interfaces, but from the way the program is running it seems much slower than simply using a for loop (1.9 sec runtime vs. .9 sec respectively). So my question is-- is it worth using functional interfaces in the place of for loops? When in general should one use functional interfaces? Are functional interfaces more efficient in some other ways? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't listen to NetBeans (which is still in alpha). Its hints would like you to use streams *everywhere*,  and that is inappropriate. Use them sparingly. See: stackoverflow.com/questions/16635398/java-8-iterable-foreach-vs-foreach-loop

Comment: Also,  you probably meant "Streams" or "lambdas" rather than "functional interfaces"

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. Hopefully NetBeans will improve soon, but hey it's the programmers job, not their job to write the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your lambdas do not use many capturing variables, then i believe that the performance will be more comparable to a standard for loop. the the advantages of using lambdas are easier parallelization (although for ordered streams this could potentially result in slower performance), and an easier to read syntax. also be aware that the hotspot compiler will change the results over time (your first loop execution will most likely be slower than your last).

i do not know the specifics, but in the worst case situation, you lambda may be implemented as an anonymous class. in the best case, it will just be a MethodHandle.

a quick test:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Random r = new Random(42);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            testFor();
            testLambda();
        }
    }

    protected static final int TestLength = 1024 * 1024 * 16;

    protected static int result;

    protected static void testFor() {
        Random r = new Random(42);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0; i < TestLength; i++) {
            result = r.nextInt(TestLength);
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.printf("testFor = %dms%n", end - start);
    }

    protected static void testLambda() {
        Random r = new Random(42);
        IntStream stream = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> r.nextInt(1024 * 1024));
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        stream.limit(TestLength).forEach(i -> {result = i;});
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.printf("testLambda = %dms%n", end - start);
    }

}
```

the results:

```
testFor = 209ms
testLambda = 207ms
testFor = 210ms
testLambda = 206ms
```

for a parallel stream the results where actually slower (around 2x on my machine) because the stream was ordered and each thread has a lot of synchronization overhead, compared to the work being done (just `result = i`)

Comment: The lambda will always be implemented as an anonymous class as the receiver expects an interface implementation, not a `MethodHandle`. That generated anonymous class may use a `MethodHandle` under the hood. The best case is that the class is shared between different lambda use sites and a single instance is used for all executions of the particular lambda use site. But in case of variable capture you will usually face different lambda classes per use site being instantiated (again) on every execution as the instance has to hold the captured values.

Comment: That is a flawed benchmark. Each iteration needs to have a useful side-effect (ie,  result += not  =),  and the result has to be used (print it).